# How to adjust initial interface of a shiny APP

Tags: css, r, shiny

I'd like to tweak my shiny code below. Therefore, I would like to adjust that part where it says `©Copyright 2022 all rights reserved` so that it is at the bottom of the page, as was done in the reference image, which is written Blog at Wordpress in the blue strip. And I would also like to insert justified to the right the icon of the following link: https://cdn-icons-png.flaticon.com/512/1701/1701585.png

```
  library(shiny)
  library(shinythemes)
  
  ui <- shiny::navbarPage(theme = shinytheme("flatly"),
                          title="Test", collapsible = TRUE,
                          
                          tabPanel("",
                                   div(
                                     style =
                                       "height: 80px;  background-color: rgba(0,0,0); width: 100%; position:absolute;right:0;",
                                     
                                     div(
                                       style = "width: 80%; margin: auto;",
                                       
                                       h1(HTML("<u> WELCOME <b>NAME</b> </u>"),
                                          style="text-align:center; color: white;"),
                                       hr(),
                                       h4(HTML("Accumsan nostra eu sodales etiam interdum lacus nullam pretium congue, dolor phasellus tincidunt metus auctor scelerisque."),
                                          
                                          style="text-align: justify"),
                                       br(),
                                       h4(HTML("The database spreadsheet can be downloaded from the following link: "),
                                          uiOutput("tab"),
                                          style="text-align: justify"),
                                       
                                       div(
                                         style = 
                                           "height: 50px; background-color: #2C3E50; width: 100%; position: absolute; margin-top: 20px;right:0; bottom:10 ;padding:0;",
                                         
                                         h5(HTML("©Copyright 2022 all rights reserved."),
                                            style="text-align: center;color: white"),
                                       br(),
                                       tags$style(".navbar {margin-bottom: 0;}"))))))
  
  
  
  
  
  server <- function(input, output,session) {
    
    url <- a("Download", href="https://google.com")
    
    output$tab <- renderUI({
      tagList(
        tags$span("",style = "font-size: 20px; font-weight: normal;"), url)
    })
  }
  
  shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

**Output**
[image]

**Example**
[image]